# html textarea to display default or the most recent input

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am building a small web query interface that has a textarea form where a user can input a query statement and PHP code that returns the result of the query or an error.

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <TEXTAREA NAME="fquery" ROWS=8 COLS=60>SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE id < 100;</TEXTAREA> <br>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

What I want to have is the text area to show that default text `"SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE id < 100;"` if this is the first query, or show the most recent input from the last time the form was submitted. Is there an HTML or PHP function that achieve this?

Comment: you can achieve this via javascript.. At first set the value of textarea on load and after user submit the data check the value of get and set that value in textarea

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in PHP to do what you want. You can include a `timestamp` in your MySQL table, though.

When selecting select the insert with the biggest timestamp (the most recent).